# Scalatest Playframework must contain List[String]

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

I am using playframework 2.4.x, and this libraries

```
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1" % "test"
"org.scalatestplus" %% "play" % "1.4.0-M3" % "test"
```

I want to check if therea are some strings in a List I build on the test, this is the code

```
val userTeams = validateAndGet((teamsUserResponse.json \ "teams").asOpt[List[TeamUser]]).map( x => x.teamKey )
userTeams must contain ("team1", "team2")
```

But I am getting this error

```
List("team1", "team2") did not contain element (team1,team2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write `("team1", "team2")` then you're actualy creating a tuple of two strings which is from perspective of the ScalaTest matcher a single element.

[Based on documentation](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers) you have to use `allOf`:

```
userTeams must contain allOf ("team1", "team2")
```

Comment: Thank you @RadoBuransky I was trying to put the elements in a List